# flashAttributes are lost during redirection at websphere

Tags: java, spring, redirect, websphere

in spring(4.3.2.RELEASE) & java(1.8) application I use spring-flashAttribute as a mechanism to pass parameters during redirection.

```
RedirectAttributes rm;
(...)
rm.addFlashAttribute("redirModel", rModel);
```

the problem is: that passing attributes (by flashAttribute) works for tomcat but for websphere(8.5.5.11) somehow these attributes are lost after redirection.

place where these attributes are passed: org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.invokeHandlerMethod(HttpServletRequest, HttpServletResponse, HandlerMethod) line 804

```
(...)
mavContainer.addAllAttributes(RequestContextUtils.getInputFlashMap(request));
(...)
```

where RequestContextUtils passes these attributes by:
org.springframework.web.servlet.support.RequestContextUtils:

```
@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
public static Map<String, ?> getInputFlashMap(HttpServletRequest request) {
    return (Map<String, ?>) request.getAttribute(DispatcherServlet.INPUT_FLASH_MAP_ATTRIBUTE);
}
```

Can someone explain how I should do it properly?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've checked and confirmed that the problem related with using flashAttribiute during redirection on websphere is caused by spring library after migration from 4.3.2.RELEASE to 4.3.9.RELEASE problem was gone.

I did not check older libraries than 4.3.9.RELEASE, so it can be fixed in older version